# Functions with compact support and $C^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given the set $D(\Omega)=\{ \phi \in C^\infty (\Omega):$  supp$(\phi):= \overline {\{x:\phi(x)\neq 0\} } \subset\Omega $ is compact$\},\, \, \Omega \subset R^n: $

1. In the case $\Omega $ is compact, can one say that $D(\Omega)= C^{\infty}(\Omega) $, since supp$(\phi)\subseteq \Omega$ ? In the case this is not true can you give an example illustrating this ?
2. In the case $\Omega $ is not compact but bounded can we still say $D(\Omega)= C^{\infty}(\Omega) $ ?
3. Let $\Omega \subset R$ be an open interval. For $f \in C^1 (\bar {\Omega})$ and $\phi \in D(\Omega)$ it follows after Integration by parts $$ \int _{\Omega} f'(x) \phi(x) \,\,dx=- \int_{\Omega} f(x) \phi'(x) \, \, dx.$$

One term of the integration by parts has disappeard because the support of $\phi$ is a compact subset of $\Omega$. Can somebody explain, why one term disappeared ? What I wrote is what is written in the book.

4. Let $\Omega = (-1,1), f(x)=|x|, \,\,  g(x)=\frac {x} {|x|} $ for $x\neq0,\,\,$ and $ g(0)=0.$ Then, $$<g,\phi>=-<f, \phi'> , \, \forall \phi \in D(\Omega), \,$$ where $<,>$ is the inner product in $L^2, $ which in our case is simply the integral of the product of the two functions.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) This is true in the sense that the restriction of the functions $\phi$ in $D(\Omega)$ are in $C^{\infty}(\Omega^{\circ})$ and $\text{supp}(\phi)$ are compact.

2) Consider $f(x)=1/x$ on $(0,1)$, then $f\in C^{\infty}(0,1)$ but $f\notin D(0,1)$.

3) Assume now in the one-dimensional, then $\Omega=(a,b)$ 
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\Omega}f'(x)\phi(x)dx\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a+1/n}^{b-1/n}f'(x)\phi(x)dx\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(b-1/n)\phi(b-1/n)-f(a+1/n)\phi(a+1/n)-\int_{a+1/n}^{b-1/n}f(x)\phi'(x)dx\\
&=-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\phi'(x)dx\\
&=-\int_{\Omega}f(x)\phi'(x)dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. How about 1) and 3) ?

Comment: Details added, you may take a look.

Comment: I still dont get it, why the term under the limit has to vanish. Can you explain it please ?

Comment: $\text{supp}(\phi)$ has an open covering $\{(a+1/n,b-1/n)\}_{n}$ and this open covering is increasing, so $\text{supp}(\phi)\subseteq(a+1/n,b-1/n)$ for all $n\geq n_{0}$.

Comment: Say, $\text{supp}(\phi)\subseteq(a+1/n_{0},b-1/n_{0})$, then surely both $a+1/n,b-1/n\notin\text{supp}(\phi)$ for all $n\geq n_{0}+1$.

Comment: Many thanks. I got it now.

Comment: Could you give me a hint, if at the point 4) the same procedure will work as in the case before, since in this case the absolute value is in the Integrand.

Comment: You can try to split the domain of the integrals to be $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$ then the absolute value issue goes away.